# How to create a gesture that changes the system volume

Tags: linux, mouse-gestures, audio-volume

Can you create a gesture that lets you do a three finger swipe, which increases and decreases the system volume?

Comment: What type of desktop environment do you use? What Linux are you running?

Comment: Do you mean "audio volume" or "system disk volume" or ...?

Comment: ubuntu and audio volume